# Check whether the set is closed/has an interior point?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $H= \{ (x_n) \in l^2: \sum_n \frac {x_n}{n}=1 \}$ Then check whether H is

$1$ Closed

$2$ Has an interior point?

I think that $H$ is closed and it does not have any interior point but i don't know how to prove it formally.Please help.

Comment: Note that $(1/n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \in \ell^2$ and use that $\ell^2 \to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto \langle x,y\rangle$ is continuous for $y \in \ell^2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX This gives $1$,what about $2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 2nd question. $H$ has no interior points.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in H$ be given. We need to find $y \in \ell^2$ such that $y \notin H$ and $\|x-y\|_2 < \varepsilon$. Choose an integer $N \geq 1$ such that 
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty {x_n^2} <1\,.
$$
Define $y \in \ell^2$ by $y_n = x_n$ for $n \leq N$ and $y_n = x_n+ 2^{-n}\varepsilon$ for $n \geq N+1$. Then 
$$\|y-x\|_2^2 = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty {2^{-2n}\varepsilon^2 x_n^2} < \varepsilon^2,$$ 
but $y \notin H$, because
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{y_n}{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{x_n}{n}} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty{\frac{2^{-n}\varepsilon}{n}}    = 1+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty{\frac{2^{-n}\varepsilon}{n}} > 1
$$